# What is the net ionic equation of the following?

Tags: aqueous-solution, stoichiometry

> Aqueous chlorine is added to a solution of aluminum bromide in a single replacement reaction which forms no precipitate and bromine liquid. Determine the net ionic equation.

Since this is a single replacement reaction, it will take the form of  $$\ce{A + B-C -> A-C + B}$$

Since this reaction forms no precipitate, the new compound will not be a solid.

$$\begin{multline}
\ce{aqueous chlorine + solution of aluminum bromide ->}\\
\ce{ non-solid compound + liquid bromine}
\end{multline}$$
\begin{align}
\ce{Cl2(aq) + Al^{3+}Br3^-(aq) &-> \text{non-solid compound} + Br2(l)}\\
\ce{Cl2(aq) + AlBr3(aq) &-> \text{non-solid compound} + Br2(l)}\\
\ce{Cl2(aq) + AlBr3(aq) &-> Al^{3+}Cl3- + Br2(l)}\\
\ce{Cl2(aq) + AlBr3(aq) &-> AlCl3 + Br2(l)}
\end{align}

Since most chloride salts are soluble (except for silver halides), $\ce{AlCl3}$ is predicted to be aqueous.

\begin{align}
\ce{Cl2(aq) + AlBr3(aq) &-> AlCl3(aq) + Br2(l)}\\
\ce{3Cl2(aq) + 2AlBr3(aq) &-> 2AlCl3(aq) + 3Br2(l)}
\end{align}

Here is the complete ionic equation:

$$\ce{6Cl⁻(aq) + 2Al^{3+}(aq) + 6Br-(aq) -> 2Al^{3+}(aq) + 6Cl-(aq) + 3Br2(l)}$$

Cancelling out the spectator ions, we get

$$\ce{6Br-(aq) -> 3Br2(l)}$$

In lowest terms:

$$\ce{2Br-(aq) -> Br2(l)}$$

Answer (score 1):

You are making a mistake splitting up your reaction equation from \eqref{full} to \eqref{wrong} in order to filter out the spectator ions.

\begin{align}
\ce{3Cl2(aq) + 2AlBr3(aq) &-> 2AlCl3(aq) + 3Br2(l)}\tag1\label{full}\\
\ce{6Cl⁻(aq) + 2Al^{3+}(aq) + 6Br-(aq) &-> 2Al^{3+}(aq) + 6Cl-(aq) + 3Br2(l)}\tag{wrong}\label{wrong}
\end{align}

What you are essentially doing is not conserving the charges. Dichlorine $\ce{Cl2}$ is a neutral molecule, and the following is what your transition implies, but is also wrong:
$$\ce{Cl2 -> 2Cl-}\tag{also wrong}$$

The correct way to transform \eqref{full} is to split (dissociate) only the ionic compounds $\ce{AlBr3}$ and \ce{AlCl3}, and then cancel the spectator ions:

\begin{align}
\ce{3 Cl2 (aq) + 2 AlBr3 (aq) &-> 2 AlCl3 (aq) + 3 Br2 (l)}\tag1\\
\ce{3 Cl2 (aq) + 2 Al^3+ (aq) + 6 Br- (aq) &-> 
    2 Al^3+ (aq) + 6 Cl- (aq) + 3 Br2 (l)}\tag2\label{split}\\
\end{align}

Next step is to cancel the aluminium ions on each side, and reduce the equation to \eqref{net-ionic}:

\begin{align}
\ce{3 Cl2 (aq) + 6 Br- (aq) &-> 6 Cl- (aq) + 3 Br2 (l)}\tag3\\
\ce{Cl2 (aq) + 2 Br- (aq) &-> 2 Cl- (aq) + Br2 (l)}\tag4\label{net-ionic}
\end{align}

I don't think the reaction will actually produce liquid bromine, but aqueous bromine instead; that doesn't matter to the solution though.

Answer (score 0):

You do not render the chlorine correctly. Keep the chlorine as diatomic molecules on the reactant side and note that **because of the charges the chlorine atoms do not cancel out**. Your net ionic equation should therefore include both halogens.